# how to resolve AWS private route53 hosted zones from GCP private compute VMs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, amazon-route53

We have a use case where we have our application deployed in AWS and GCP and the applications communicate by the hostname of the servers.

We are able to setup the VPN between AWS and GCP, and it is working fine. Now we are facing an issue when we are trying to connect to the servers of AWS from GCP by their hostnames and vice-versa. Servers are not able to resolve hostname to IP. For example we have one server in AWS which has hostname "ip-10-0-1-11" and one server in GCP which has hostname "worker-1". Now we want GCP VM "worker" to able to connect to AWS VM "ip-10-0-1-11" by hostname, e.g. `ping ip-10-0-1-11` but we are getting below error:

```
root@dlos-controller:/# ping ip-10-0-1-11
ping: ip-10-0-1-11: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Looking forward for your support on this.

Comment: Looks like this guide might be what you are looking for https://medium.com/searce/resolve-aws-rds-and-other-dns-names-on-vpn-networks-using-r53-resolvers-55ec68271270

Comment: @EmilGi thanks, it helped.